# Redirect subdirectory to parent folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following file structure

```
- example.com
- - app
- - - index.html
- - api
- - - index.php
```

How can I redirect my domain
local.example.com to app/*
and local.example.com/api/ to api/* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `local.example.com`'s document root is `example.com` folder...

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder `example.com`)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:api|app)/)(.*)$ /app/$1 [L]
```